# How to make a video of two images morphing into each other?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing

I wanted to make a short video of one image becoming another, in a sort of transformation. I thought that some kind of interpolation could help me so i downloaded ffmpeg. But I don't really now how to do it. I think I need to first make a video with only 2 frames and them use interpolation to do the magic, but I'm not really sure. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Not sure using ffmpeg, but see https://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/picture-morphing.shtml for other software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this old, but very good program: [Sqirlz Morph](http://www.xiberpix.net/SqirlzMorph.html).

Its advantage is that it's a freeware, it has graphical interface, it's own help and tutorial, and it's easy to use.

[image]